# One way slide transitions

Tags: beamer, transition

Is there a way to have a transitions only if coming from a particular ''direction'' in beamer?

I explain myself better. I'm doing a presentation and when I come to a particular slide from the linear workflow I want the transition to happen; I then have a reference in the appendix to the same slide and if I come from there I don't want the transition.

[Here is the link to a the MWE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x3i34krc2wp40bj/fIfrj2B-QG), (currently) the same as the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\mode<beamer>
{
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First slide}
some stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{I want transition}{\transwipe[direction=180, duration=0.6]}
\label{trans-slide}
I want a transition if I come from the first slide

I don't want it if I come from the appendix
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}{Appendix}

\hyperlink{trans-slide}{\beamergotobutton{I don't want transition}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Transitions are seperate pdf pages. So what you want to do is a PDF page jump and I don't think you can achieve that unless the viewer has such specification capability. So this is more of a PDF viewer spec question rather than beamer.

Comment: I understand, that's a pity...